# Toolbar placed as bottom bar does not show line similar to top bar

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am opening a view as fullScreenCover and adding top and bottom bar to it. I am using iOS 16.4

When I add a toolbar at top, iOS automatically adds a horizontal divider line but does not do the same for bottom bar. It doesn't even allow me to add an overlay so I can create a rectangle around bottom bar which will show the divider line. How can I add a horizontal divider line for bottom bar (similar to one marked with arrow in the attached screenshot)?

Note: I have too much of code so just adding code within 'fullScreenCover' modifier. But all the toolbar code is in this snippet. If more code is needed, please let me know.

Edit: If a line cannot be added, then how do I add a background color. As mentioned, whenever I try to add an overlay or any other element, I am seeing errors.

***Code:***

```
.fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showAttachment) {
NavigationStack {
    CustomView.
        .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
                Button {
                    self.showAttachment = false
                    self.showAttachmentHeader = false
                }
            label: {
                Text(Strings.done).font(.body.bold())
            }
                
            }

            ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
                // TODO: Add a button to "share image"
                Spacer()
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    Text("6 Attachments")
                    .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 12))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)

                    Text("1 of 6")
                    .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 11))
                    .kerning(0.066)
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.24, green: 0.24, blue: 0.26).opacity(0.6))
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .toolbarBackground(Color.lightGray, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .navigationBar)
        .toolbarBackground(Color.lightGray, for: .bottomBar)
        .toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .bottomBar)
        .toolbar(.visible, for: .bottomBar)
}
}
```

[image]

Comment: The line will be there if there is content behind the toolbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just put a `Divider` at the top of the `VStack` inside your `ToolbarItemGroup`.

- If you take out the two `Spacer` then the `Divider` automatically uses the full width, apart from some leading and trailing insets.
- I would say, the insets look quite good. But if you want the divider to extend to the edges then applying negative horizontal padding seems to work (commented out in snippet below).
- If you need more vertical spacing then you could add padding to the content.

```swift
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
    VStack {
        Divider()
        //  .padding(.horizontal, -30)

        // other content as before
    }
}
```

[image]

---

*EDIT* Follow up to comments

Here's another variation, using a colored background with a shadow.

```swift
ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
    VStack {
        // as before, without Divider
    }
    .padding(.top, 20)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(
        Color.yellow
            .padding(.horizontal, -30)
            .padding(.bottom, -100)
            .shadow(radius: 5)
    )
}
```

[image: WithBackground]

Comment: Yeah I gave it a try just few minutes back and was able to do it with VStack. I was trying to add a background color as well so it looks better and wrapped entire VStack within ZStack and added color to it, but looks like iOS is limiting the insets on bottom bar probably as with toolbar it's adding background color only to half of the bar. However what you posted works.

Comment: I think the ```Spacer``` around the ```VStack``` work horizontally, not vertically. When you take them out, the ```VStack``` fills the full width, apart from the leading and trailing insets. You can add a background color to the ```VStack``` and it works fine. Negative padding can be used to stretch the background to the edges.

Comment: which iOS version you are using? I tried adding background on VStack within ToolbarItemGroup and it looks similar to screenshot I attached in Solution 1 for my answer below. It doesn't apply the background completely to safe area insets.

Comment: iOS 16.4. Answer updated with example.

Comment: This approach worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's difficult to add background color to the bottom bar. Posting whatever I tried so far for others, but hasn't been able to add background color suggesfully.

**Solution 1:**

```
.toolbar {
    ToolbarItem(placement: .confirmationAction) {
        Button {
            self.showAttachment = false
            self.showAttachmentHeader = false
        }
    label: {
        Text(Strings.done).font(.body.bold())
    }
        
    }
    
    ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .bottomBar) {
        ZStack {
            Color.systemLightGray.ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack {
                Divider().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0.25).overlay(Color.systemMediumGray)
                    VStack(alignment: .center) {
                        Text("6 Attachments")
                        .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 12))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)

                        Text("1 of 6")
                        .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 11))
                        .kerning(0.066)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.24, green: 0.24, blue: 0.26).opacity(0.6))
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 10.0)
            }
        }
    }
    
}
.toolbarBackground(Color.lightGray, for: .navigationBar, .bottomBar)
.toolbarBackground(.visible, for: .navigationBar, .bottomBar)
.toolbar((self.showAttachmentHeader ? .visible : .hidden), for: .navigationBar, .bottomBar)
```

With solution 1: Seems like iOS is limiting the insets on bottom bar as it is applying the background color only on half bar like below.

[image]

***Solution 2***: I tried creating a custom bottom bar and tried adding as an overlay on my CustomView. With that am able to add background color, but it somehow leaves space between divider and the content.

***Code for solution 2:***

```
CustomView
.overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
    VStack {
        Divider()
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 0.25)
            .overlay(Color.systemMediumGray)
            .background(Color.lightGray)
        ZStack {
            Color.lightGray.ignoresSafeArea()
                    VStack {
                        Text("6 Attachments")
                        .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 12))
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)

                        Text("1 of 6")
                        .font(Font.custom("SF Pro Text", size: 11))
                        .kerning(0.066)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                        .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.24, green: 0.24, blue: 0.26).opacity(0.6))
                    }
            }
    }
    .frame(height: 80.0)
}
```

***Screenshot from solution 2:***

[image]